# How to get an interface's properties from typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to get a "postType" Property from an interface defined like this

```
export interface PostType {
  postType: {
    title?: string;
    content?: string;
  };
}
```

The purpose I want to take out and use the "postType" Property is as follows

```
const fn = (post: Post) => {
  ...
}
```

I used "Pick" but this doesn't work.

```
export type Post = Pick<PostType, 'postType'>;
```

The reason I've configured the interface above is that PostType is actually a property that corresponds to another interface.

So I have to follow PostType's interface.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you want to do this: `PostType["postType"]`

Comment: This is the correct answer but in the future please flag duplicates for closure rather than answering them.